# Apache logging to different files by response code

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have an apache web server which is configured to allow access via client certificate to only a few people.  I cannot lock down by IP because the certificate holders could potentially connect from anywhere.

Apache currently returns 403 to anyone not presenting a valid certificate or trying to access an invalid URL, but since the machine has no ACL restrictions it is frequently scanned for vulnerabilities.  These scans cause quite a lot of noise in the logs.

Is there a way to log to a different file based on the response code?  Is it possible to send all logging for requests which result in a 403 to a different file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get Apache to pipe the custom log to a script. So for example, change the CustomLog entry in the vhost to:

`CustomLog "|/path/to/script"`

The you can have a script that does something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while ($log = <STDIN>) {
    if ($log =~ /403/) {
        open(LOG, '>>/path/to/403log');
        print LOG $log;
        close(LOG);
    } else {
        open(LOG, '>>/path/to/mainlog');
        print $log LOG;
        close(LOG);
    }
}
```

The above script is untested, but it should give you an idea of what you can do.

Comment: That's cool. :) Another approach using CustomLog: if using syslog-ng, you can use CustomLog directive like `CustomLog "/usr/bin/logger ..."` and then do the log file separation in syslog-ng pattern matching.

Comment: Yup, that would also work. +1